# Namespace is defined despite never being imported

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Libraries or typings with an **export as namespace** declaration appear to be automatically polluting my code's namespace, despite me never importing them.

For example:

```
import * as bar from "exa";

export var t2 = (a:foo.Test) => { 
    console.log(a.doSomething());
}

export class Something {
    public test(c:foo.Test) {
        c.doSomething();
    }
}
```

[Complete example on GitHub](https://github.com/corruptmem/ts-namespace-issue)

What I would expect to happen is to get an error when I try to reference "foo", as I have not explicitly imported it or defined it anywhere. However, this compiles successfully.

According to the [TypeScript 2.0 Handbook](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#support-for-umd-module-definitions), namespaces exported with a **export as namespace** declaration should only be available if you are writing a script, which they define as *"a file with no imports or exports"*. However in the example above, I have one import and two exports, so I don't think it counts as a script?

Therefore, why am I able to reference "foo" from my code?

This is being compiled with TypeScript 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only allowed to reference `foo` in *type* positions without an `import`. Attempting to use `foo` in a *value* position will raise an error.

This is because TS doesn't want to force you to write an `import` solely to get type information into scope, since `import`s have runtime side effects which you may not want.

Comment: So imports aren't necessary, for example, if you just want to decorate your function's parameter with a type?  In that case, say I was to remove the "export as namespace" declaration, how would I reference the Test interface without an import if it was exported inside a "declare module" scope?

Comment: Also: "A key feature of modules in TypeScript is that two different modules will never contribute names to the same scope. [..]  the consumer of a module decides what name to assign it" (from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html): doesn't this example potentially violate that?